# What is tomcat's performance limit?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, load-testing

Short question: My tomcat server is maxing out at 850 MBytes/Second. Is this logical?

I am trying to benchmark my tomcat installation. The server is a back-end storage server which I would like to reach speeds of ~2.5 GBytes/S per second (30 gBits) . This is not an internet server. It is a cloud computing node, with several fiber cards. I am interested in going as close to the theoretical limit as possible.

When bench-marking with real S/W my performance was sub-par. I tested tomcat with a "dummy" servelet (below). I maxed out at 850 MBytes/s. But my CPU is only 30% busy. Is this logical?

I am using apache ab to test:

```
ab -c 100 -n 10000  localhost:8080/tcbench/tcbench
```

My setup is E31260L XEON with 32GB of memory, Ubuntu 12.04 and Oracale tomcat7 with JDK 7 (default config files).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
public class tcbench extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/text;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            out.print(testBuffer);
        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }

    static char[] testBuffer=new char[128*1024];

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try running a different light weight server, for example Nginx -and serve just large text files. That should give you a bandwidth benchmark to compare against.

Comment: Tried two other options: Static 128k file from Apache - 1.5gBps. Jetty - 500 gBps. This is strange, I would have expected Apache to be faster. What could be limitting my speed?

Comment: Have you looked at [Apache Portable Runtime (APR) based Native library for Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html)?

Comment: What does the hard disk I/O look like?

Comment: Try profiling, it would be interesting whats taking the time... you might consider tuning the GC. There are quite some tips on the web how to tune tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not CPU bound ... that typically means something else is holding you back.

Are you using an access logger or other logging?